# Why does Activity display Title yet by default?

Tags: android

From some doucment , I know ActionBarActivity display app title by default. I create a Activity with eclipse, I have set android:theme as android:Theme.Light, I find the Activity still display Title by default, why?

[image]

```
package com.example.aa;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}



<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.aa"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>


<resources>

    <!--
        Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
        by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
    -->
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
        <!--
            Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
            res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
            backward-compatibility can go here.
        -->
    </style>

    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    </style>

</resources>



<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: 1. Always use the latest APIs in Android. 2. Target API 22, use `AppCompatActivity`. 3. Use `Theme.AppCompat.Light.` instead of the old `android:Theme.Light`. 4. Use Intellij or Android Studio.

Comment: Thanks! but in the latest APIs,  openOptionsMenu() don't work, would you  please have a look at   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30836794/why-dont-i-open-option-menu-by-click-a-button-when-i-use-actionbaractivity-in-a

Comment: Once again, you are using older APIs. You are using `ActionBarActivity`. You need to be using `AppCompatActivity`.

Comment: Thank! I need the app can run under android 2.3.3, and ActionBarActivit is created automatically by Android Studio 1.2.2 wizard, can I always using AppCompatActivity instead of Activity?

Comment: `ActionBarActivity` is deprecated. Use AppCompat 22.2.0.

Comment: Thanks! just now I use AppCompatActivity instead of ActionBarActivit , but I get the same result,  openOptionsMenu() don't work yet!

Comment: Why do you need this functionality? What are you really trying to do?

Comment: To  Jared Burrows:  I have answered "why do you need the functionality", would you please see my modified quesion at  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30836794/why-dont-i-open-option-menu-by-click-a-button-when-i-use-actionbaractivity-in-a.Thanks!

Comment: popup menu can do that, but it require API 11, my min API is 9 :(  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#options-menu

Comment: app compatv7 provides PopupMenu for API 7+. This is **exactly** why I asked you **why**.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting this to your activity declared in the manifest:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
```

Comment: He is using App Compat, why do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
//Remove title bar
this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

//Remove notification bar
this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

//set content view AFTER ABOVE sequence (to avoid crash)
this.setContentView(R.layout.your_layout_name_here);
```

Be certain to put it before the call to setContentView(R.id.x), otherwise it will crash. The reason wasn't immediately obvious to me. 08-13 12:47:33.561 E/AndroidRuntime( 9125): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.myapp/com.myapp.SplashActivity}: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content